# GET Request uses too many parameters- iOS

Tags: ios, http, get

I'm trying to load a URL in NSMutableURLRequest for a GET request as below:

```
 NSString *serverAddress =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.us.to:8080/api/offers?altId=%@&provider=%@&otherId=%@&tenantId=%@&createdAt=%@&otherOfferId=%@&postId=%@&pageId=%@&sourceUrl=%@&name=%@&description=%@&text=%@&category=%@&caption=%@&startTime=%@&expirationTime=%@&minPurchase=%@&numPurchases=%@&value=%@&percent=%@&count=%@&currency=%@&terms=%@&campaignId=%@&partnerId=%@&tenantIdAtPartner=%@&issuerName=%@&claimLimit=%@&onePerUser=%@&emailTemplateFile=%@",@"test",@"Facebook",@"",@"test",@"null",@"test",@"",@"",@"http://test.us.to/offers/harvester_summer13.html",@"Harvester",@"Harvester 2for1 TakeAway",@"Enjoy!",@"voucher",@"Harvester 2for1 TakeAway",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"test",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"1000",[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"GBP",@"",[NSNumber numberWithInt:1259],@"null" ,@"null" ,@"null",[NSNumber numberWithInt:100],[NSNumber numberWithBool:false],@"templates/test.vm"];

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[serverAddress urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData timeoutInterval:15.0];

 NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"testuser", @"testpwd"];
 NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
 [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];



 [request setHTTPMethod: @"GET"];

 NSError *requestError;
 NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

 NSData *response1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
```

NSLog(@"output data %@",response1);

I guess I'm loading way too many parameters using the url string. Is there a better way to pass parameters for a GET request ? The current output is null for response1

Comment: How do you know you have too many parameters?

Comment: Isn't there a limit for a GET request? 256 characters?

Comment: It looks like you're encoding the whole serverAddress string. Shouldn't you just be encoding the parameters after the url address?

Comment: There's no specific limit. It depends on the web server and the OS. I'm pretty sure Mobile Safari can handle URLs that are over 2500 characters.

Comment: Rather than reinvent the wheel, you may want to look at the highly polished methods in AFNetworking that do this: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m - see `AFQueryStringFromParametersWithEncoding`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue is that you are encoding the whole url with some sort of encoding method, but you really just need to encode each parameter separately if it contains certain characters. For example:

```
NSString *serverAddress = @"http://test.us.to:8080/api/offers";

NSString *altIdParameter = [@"Escape?This?String?" urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *aUrlParameter = [@"http://test.us.to/offers/harvester_summer13.html" urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *getRequestUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:%@?altId=%@&urlParam=%@", serverAddress, altIdParameter, aUrlParameter];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getRequestUrl];
```